# How to disable simple product URL rewrite management by Magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

I have 3 online stores running on a single Magento installation.

They share over 10.000+ SKU's (I've set them up as simple products), but the only products visible on the frontend are the Grouped Products for each store (which have the SKU's associated to them).

As such, my URL rewrite table is very heavy and while checking Varien Profiler I came across "mage::dispatch::routers_match" which is taking more than 5 seconds to complete. I reckon this is because it's such a large table. So that brings me to my question:

How do I specify which URL's I wan't Magento to rewrite. Is there anyway I can tell it to NOT rewrite simple products URLs? That alone would bring down the table to 1/3rd.

PS: Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Edit:

Thank you Tobias for pointing me in the right direction. I went to app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php and edited the function `refreshProductRewrites` to this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
        if($product->getTypeId() == "simple"){
            continue;
        }
        else {
        $this->_refreshProductRewrite($product, $this->_categories[$storeRootCategoryId]);
        foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId) {
            if ($categoryId != $storeRootCategoryId && isset($this->_categories[$categoryId])) {
                if (strpos($this->_categories[$categoryId]['path'], $storeRootCategoryPath . '/') !== 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                $this->_refreshProductRewrite($product, $this->_categories[$categoryId]);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collection for the products which are stored in **`core_url_rewrite`** is generated in **`Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`** refreshProductRewrites.

You could rewrite this class and implement your own implementation, which only stores the grouped products.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, please check my edit. Would that work? I realize I'm not supposed to mess with the core code, I'll rewrite the class if it indeed works.

Comment: Yes that would work. But it's not the best solution in case of performance, you could try to do the filter already in SQL, but it looks like you also have to rewrite the resource for url, to extend the getProductsByStore method

Comment: True, but that worked for now and I already did the reindex. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is just ignoring the products that have an empty url key.

```
   protected function _refreshProductRewrite(Varien_Object $product, Varien_Object $category)
   {
   if ($category->getId() == $category->getPath()) {
   return $this;
   }
   if ($product->getUrlKey() != '') {

   $urlKey = $this->getProductModel()->formatUrlKey($product->getUrlKey());
```

You can clear the url keys for the simple products by (check the attribute id):

DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE type_id='simple' AND attribute_id='97');